# Overwrite NULL result in query with next NOT NULL value

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables:

**t1**

```
t1.id | t1.val   
----- | ------  
    1 |   a  
    2 |   b  
    3 |   c  
    4 |   d  
    5 |   e  
    6 |   f  
    7 |   j
```

and **t2**

```
t2.id|t2.val   
---- | ---  
    1| www  
    3| xxx  
    6| yyy  
    7| zzz
```

When I apply such sql-instruction:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.val, t2.val
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON ( t1.id = t2.id )
```

And result gives same table

```
t1.id | t1.val | t2.val   
----- | ------ | ------  
    1 | a | www  
    2 | b | NULL  
    3 | c | xxx  
    4 | d | NULL  
    5 | e | NULL  
    6 | f | yyy  
    7 | j | zzz
```

Help me change the sql-instruction if I want to get result like this

```
t1.id | t1.val | t2.val   
----- | ------ | ------  
    1 | a | www  
    2 | b | xxx  
    3 | c | xxx  
    4 | d | yyy  
    5 | e | yyy  
    6 | f | yyy  
    7 | j | zzz
```

Thanks for all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.val
        from t2
        where t2.id >= t1.id
        order by t2.id
        limit 1
       ) as t2val
from t1;
```

Another method uses window functions, but it is a bit more complicated:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.val, t2.val
FROM (SELECT t1.id, t1.val,
             MIN(t2.id) OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) as matching_id
      FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
           t2
           ON t1.id = t2.id
     ) t LEFT JOIN
     t2
     ON t2.id = t.matching_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT t1.id, t1.val, NVL(t2.val,LEAD(t2.val) OVER (ORDER BY t2.id))
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON ( t1.id = t2.id )